# How to curl or wget the content of a url

Tags: git, curl, gerrit

I want to download the file from a gerrit url something like

```
https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=mdsal.git;a=blob_plain;f=model/ietf/ietf-yang-types/src/main/yang/ietf-yang-types.yang;hb=HEAD
```

I tried my luck with wget and curl but instead of downloading the raw content at the above url I am getting the html content but I want the raw only as we get on `https://raw.githubusercontent.com`

Command that I used:

```
 wget https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=mdsal.git;a=blob_plain;f=model/ietf/ietf-yang-types/src/main/yang/ietf-yang-types.yang;hb=HEAD
 curl https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=mdsal.git;a=blob_plain;f=model/ietf/ietf-yang-types/src/main/yang/ietf-yang-types.yang;hb=HEAD
```

I got the same html output but I want the raw content of the file only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put quotes around the URL. The `;` character is probably tripping you up - the shell will read up to there and then treat the `;` as the end of the command.

Try:

```
wget 'https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=mdsal.git;a=blob_plain;f=model/ietf/ietf-yang-types/src/main/yang/ietf-yang-types.yang;hb=HEAD'
curl 'https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=mdsal.git;a=blob_plain;f=model/ietf/ietf-yang-types/src/main/yang/ietf-yang-types.yang;hb=HEAD'
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php    
$url = 'https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=mdsal.git;a=blob_plain;f=model/ietf/ietf-yang-types/src/main/yang/ietf-yang-types.yang;hb=HEAD';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

Though I'm unsure why you would get html via the other methods as the content type is text/plain; for the resource ... If this answer does not give you the desired result please be more specific.